# bash переименование файлов

Tags: bash

ребят 
не могу решить, как с какой стороны подступить

Задача 
переименовать все файлы в папке

```
> file.txt -> file.new.txt  
> file space.txt -> file space.new.txt
> file.txt.txt.txt -> file.txt.txt.new.txt 
> FILE.TXT -> FILE.new.txt
```

есть решение которое покрывает все кроме 2 последних 
уже сбился как пытался сделать...

На bash

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file 
do 
  res=${file/'.txt'/'.new.txt'}
  cp '$file' '$res'
done
```

Comment: А file.Txt и FiLe.tXt куда?

Comment: вот собственно я не могу понять как в разделе ${file/... сделать нечувствительным к регистру...

Comment: Меня больше смущает почему везде new, а в последнем примере внезапно NEW?

Comment: ето я так написал уже.. по сути .new.txt везде

Comment: Тогда проще отрезать последние 4 символа и не заморачиваться. Они точно .txt по условиям поиска

Comment: да пнул в нужном направлении !) Спасибо !)

Comment: `$ prename -n -v 's/\.txt$/.new$&/i' *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось не совсем красиво но тем не менее, можно использовать

```
find . -iname "*.txt" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file 
do 
  res=${file::-4}".new.txt"
  cp '$file' '$res'
done
```

Answer (score 3):

более компактный вариант [предыдущего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1033436/178576):

```
$ find . -iname \*.txt -exec bash -c 'f="{}"; mv "$f" "${f::-4}.new.txt"' \;
```

другой вариант, с использованием perl-ового скрипта *prename* (входит в одноимённый пакет):

```
$ prename 's/\.txt$/.new.txt/i' *
```